# how to call phtml file in email template in magento2

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.3, email-templates, phtml

I need to pass the phtml file into email template. but I'm getting error like

> Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'Vendor_Module::emailproducts.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'

I used below code in email template.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="email_template" area='frontend' template="Vendor_Module::emailproducts.phtml"}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Phtml template file path ?

Comment: what is the location of your phtml file ?

Comment: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/emailproducts.phtml

Comment: app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates path you add phtml file in templates folder

Comment: sanni Kalariya can you explain clearly

Comment: create email folder and put file in this folder and then call => {{block class='Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\Template' area='frontend' template='Vendor_Module::email/emailproducts.phtml'}}

Comment: Not working Savan Patel. Same error

Comment: @venkataprasad ple explain clearly ?what to get?

Comment: What email are you sending? Is your current area frontend?

Comment: please check you have created template folder instead of templates ?Magento 2 have foldername templates => app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/emailproducts.phtml

Comment: Yes I'm created the templates folder.Still same error

Comment: Custom email I'm sending.in that email I'm passing the custom phtml file. yes it is current area frontend @KristofatFooman

Comment: @venkataprasad is **Vendor_Module** module is properly registered, means functionality you written in Vendor_Module is working, if working then check module dependency.

Answer (score 3):

> Steps to call PHTML file in custom email template:

1. Write below code in email template to call custom phtml file.

   You can pass custom data in $custom_var to PHTML file.

```
{{layout handle="custom_email_data" custom_var=$custom_var area="frontend"}}
```

2. Create layout file at below path :

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/custom_email_data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Custom email data" >
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_email_data" template="Vendor_Module::email/custom.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. Create PHTML file at below path :

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/email/custom.phtml**

```
<?php 

/*** Get custom variable data ***/
 echo $block->getCustomVar(); 

?>
```