# call phtml file in custom email template in magento2

Tags: magento2, email, magento2.3, phtml

I need to pass the phtml file into email template. but I'm getting error like

**Error Log :**

> Error filtering template: Invalid template file:
>   'Vendor_Module::emailproducts.phtml' in module: '' block's name:
>   'magento\framework\view\element\template_0'

**I used below code in email template.**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="email_template" area='frontend' template="Vendor_Module::emailproducts.phtml"}}
```

**Phtml template file path**

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/emailproducts.phtml
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: phtml file destination is in custom module?

Comment: What is the location of your template?

Comment: Template path should app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/email/emailproducts.phtml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call phtml file in email template in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272771/how-to-call-phtml-file-in-email-template-in-magento2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass something like below in your email.html file.

```
<td>
   {{layout handle="product_stock_alert_items"}}
</td>
```

Create layout file as product_stock_alert_items.xml in layout folder. Add content in it like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" design_abstraction="custom">
        <body>
             <block class="Magento\ProductAlert\Block\Email\Stock" name="productalert.stock.alert" template="Magento_ProductAlert::stock.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </body>
    </page>
```

And now create .phtml as stock.phtml in template folder and add your phtml content in it.

Comment: Magento 1 How to add website filter in app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new.phtml, my workout => https://paste.ofcode.org/G7k6QZMMEMHE8yHCH3kj6z any help thanks @Kazim Noorani

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your Email template file. Your given template file is not found in an assigned block`(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template)`.  so you need to create a custom block and have to assign that block to the phtml file.

And extend your custom block to `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

Check below detail description example.

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/email/test_reminder.html

```
<tr class="email-information">
    <td>
        {{layout handle="test_email_log_order_items" items=$items area="frontend"}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/test_email_log_order_items.xml

```
<block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\EmailLog\Items" name="items" template="email/items.phtml" cacheable="false"></block>
```

> Namespace\Modulename\Block\EmailLog\Items

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\EmailLog;

class Items extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
        array $data = array()
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);        
    }        

}
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml

```
<?php
echo "This data is dynamic data and can be changed according to need.";
// You can print data according to your need. 
// You can also get the parameters on this file.
?>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/email_templates.xml

```
<template id="test_email_template" label="Test email template" file="test_reminder.html" type="html" module="Namespace_Modulename" area="frontend"/>
```

If you are giving a select email template in system configuration then your `config.xml` should be like below.

> app/code/Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml

```
<default>
    <tabname>            
        <groupname>                
            <fieldname>test_email_template</fieldname>
        </groupname>            
    </tabname>
</default>
```

That's it. It's work for me! I hope it helps.